# Need help creating and installing capnpc-java (CapnProto for Java)

Tags: java, linux, cmake, protocol-buffers, capnproto

I have a project requiring the use of Cap'n Proto for Java. I have a Linux system and I've successfully installed the Cap'n Proto schema compiler as described here:

https://capnproto.org/install.html

Now following the installation instructions as described here: https://dwrensha.github.io/capnproto-java/index.html, I can't seem to figure out how to generate the `capnpc-java` plugin. The instructions here seem unclear:

> You will need to install the latest release of the Cap’n Proto schema compiler. Then, running make should build capnpc-java.

Running make from where?  I did that from the `$WORKDIR/capnproto-java` directory but that doesn't work.

The other approach I did was to follow the `cmake` instructions from from `$WORKDIR/capnproto-java/cmake/README.md` but that didn't work either. According to that README.md:

`mkdir build`
`cd build`
`cmake -DCAPNP_PKG_PATH=[path of Capnproto pkgconfig directory (with capnp.pc)] [path of CMakeLists.txt]`

Where I set `CAPNP_PKG_PATH` to be the path of the `$WORKDIR/capnproto/c++/pkgconfig` directory, and the `[path of CMakeLists.txt]` to `$WORKDIR/capnproto`, where `$WORKDIR` is a directory on my system.

Can anyone help?  I'm not an expert on make system, Makefiles, or cmake. Where does the `capnpc-java` created?  When I do a `which capnpc-java`, nothing is showing up (I do however, can successfully `which capnp`, which is located in `/usr/local/bin/`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like I figured it out after some trial and error. It's not straightforward from the README, but at the end of the day, I got the `capnpc-java` built. This is the approach I did:

1. Per https://capnproto.org/install.html, follow the instructions **From Git**
2. Go to `$WORKDIR/capnproto-java/cmake`. Follow the instructions in the `README.md` inside that `cmake` directory, under **Using cmake**.
3. When specifying `-DCAPNP_PKG_PATH`, specify the path from Step 1, but make sure to include `capnp.pc`. For example: `cmake -DCAPNP_PKG_PATH=$WORKDIR/capnproto/c++/pkgconfig/capnp.pc $WORKDIR/capnproto/CMakeLists.txt`
4. `cd` to `$WORKDIR/capnproto` and run `make -j6`
5. `cd` to `$WORKDIR/capnproto-java` and run `make`
6. `capnpc-java` is generated in `$WORKDIR/capnproto-java`.  Copy this to `/usr/local/bin`

I'm assuming this works.  I haven't run the `capnp compile` yet, but at least this answered my original question.

Comment: **UPDATE**: As of 2018-10-04, due to some updates in the main capnp branch, if the above steps fail to compile for you, do the following:

* In Step 3, the last argument should now be `$WORKDIR/capnproto/c++/CMakeLists.txt`
* In Step 5, modify the `Makefile`, and change the `-std=` c++ flags from `c++11` to `c++14`